# How to generate production build of angular 2 lazy loaded application using gulp?

Tags: angular, gulp, systemjs

I am learning angular 2. I Have created sample application with lazy loaded modules.  I am using systemjs builder with gulp to create build. If I run the app using systemjs then it work's fine but if I take production build using systemjs builder then it gives error for lazy loaded modules. Can anyone give a a correct way to generate production build using gulp?